# Is it possible to do a setIntField() here ? an int in the place of Long in JNI

Tags: android, java-native-interface

Is it possible to change this snippet of code so that SetLongField become setIntField ?

```
jobject nbField ;
UL l_ul_NbField ;

jclass longClass = i_env->GetObjectClass(nbField);
jfieldID val = i_env->GetFieldID(longClass, "value", "J");
i_env->SetLongField(nbField, val, (L)l_ul_NbField);
```

When I do :

```
jclass intClass = i_env->GetObjectClass(nbField);
jfieldID val = i_env->GetFieldID(intClass, "value", "I");
i_env->SetIntField(nbField, val, (I)l_ul_NbField);
```

It **crashes** ! Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make sure what type nbField is? If nbField has type Long, then `i_env->GetFieldID(intClass, "value", "I");` returns null, so calling setIntField causes crash.